# Is there a buffer caching application that preloads streaming video?

Tags: streaming, rtmp, vlc, media

I'm trying to find out if there's already a application in existence or a way to preload (cache/ buffer) couple minutes ahead of live streaming media 
e.g. live stream onine TV, rtmp protocol etc..
in order to play it smooth on vlc media player and even at low bandwidths. 
I don't mind getting the live feed 30 minutes later.

another hint:
VLC media player only allows 9999 ms buffer time for streams and am looking for some way to expand this ..by 10 min or so :)

Answer (score 1):

Launch VLC. Go to `Open Network Stream`. After specifying the URL, select `Convert` in place of `Play`.  Choose `Dump raw input`. In destination file, specify `somefilename.ts`. Wait 10 minutes. Launch another VLC instance. Play `somefilename.ts`